# Autonaming "Input Type's checkbox's name" in html form

Tags: php, html

Basically I want to automatically create a new name for the `INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX` 
maybe like

`input type=checkbox name=ORDER1`

And

`input type=checkbox name=ORDER2`

And so on

While reading it from the database. but I don't know how to do that, need some guide here.

```
<form method=POST action="order.php">
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM product";
$exe = mysql_query($query);

echo "<div align=center><b> YOUMIND FASHION STORE </b></div><br><br>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe))
{
$a = $row['name'];
$b = $row['price'];
$c = $row['weight'];
$d = $row['pics'];
$e = $row['id_product'];
echo "<table width='320' border='1' align='center'>
      <br>
          <img src='$d' width='300' height='300'><br><br>       
          <tr><td><br>Name : $a <br>
          Price : $b <br><br> 
          <INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='WGHITEM' VALUE=$b></INPUT>
          <INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' NAME='WGH' VALUE=$c></INPUT>
```

Now here is the problem

```
          <INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME='ORDER' VALUE=$e> Check This item</INPUT><br><br> 


</td></tr></table>";
    }        
<input type="submit" value="ORDER">
</form>
```

Comment: Care with HTML attributes, the should be surrounded by " (double quotes), not simple quotes (type, name) or nothing (value).

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_query` functions anymore. Use PDO or mysqli instead. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable with starting value = 1, then you can increase it and you can use the number in your ORDER name like this:

```
<form method=POST action="order.php">
<?php
      include 'connection.php';
      $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
      $exe = mysql_query($query);

        echo "<div align=center><b> YOUMIND FASHION STORE </b></div><br><br>";

        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($exe))
        {
            $a = $row['name'];
            $b = $row['price'];
            $c = $row['weight'];
            $d = $row['pics'];
            $e = $row['id_product'];
            echo '<table width="320" border="1" align="center">
            <br>
            <img src="'.$d.'" width="300" height="300"><br><br>       
            <tr><td><br>Name : '.$a.' <br>
            Price : '.$b.' <br><br> 
            <input type="hidden" name="WGHITEM" value="'.$b.'"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="WGH" value="'.$c.'"></input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ORDER'.$i.'" value="'.$e.'"> Check This item</input><br><br> 

        </td></tr></table>';
        $i++;
        }    
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="ORDER">
</form>
```

You should use class and css for styling the table, instead of width, border and align attributes!